# Oauth for vendor

Tags: oauth, codenameone

I am looking to have vendors use google Oauth to ensure that they are the owner of a company. Is this possible. I have googled and found nothing about this. I want for example bobs pizza to log into my app and change things about bobs pizza and want to use google Oauth to do it. If I can not does anyone have an idea of how to do this? I want the confirmation of the company to be done by a third party like google, facebook, bb ...    I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is Google or Facebook login.

This [Codename One blog](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html) has a detailed step by step details on how to do that.

And here is one for [Facebook login](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-3.html).

Comment: This will let a user log in using google or facebook. However, I need to connect that with a business. For example if the owner pats pizza logs into my app I want them to be able to change data in my database that is relevant to pats pizza. I need to connect the login to pats pizza. I don't know how to connect the google login with the business that is associated with it. I have already done both google and FB login in another app. So I get that part. Again THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!